# In Xul or javascript, is there a way to hide the mouse cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor, xul

In Xul or javascript, is there a way to hide the mouse cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#elementID{
     cursor: none;
  }
```

Check out [MDC:Cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/cursor). Its CSS3, so only supported in CSS3 compatible browsers.

Comment: @Tom: MDC says so and i trust MDC. I think it wont work at IE6 :)

Comment: Ah, ok.. maybe for IE 6 you are right. But don't bet all your chips in MDC.

Answer (score 1):

If CSS can be applied in XUL, use
cursor: none;

Answer (score 1):

In XUL chrome windows you can also use the global [setCursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setCursor) function, which overrides the cursor for a whole DOM window at once (but no subframes). It takes a single parameter which is one of the CSS cursor values.